# Convert a simple command from cmd to a batch file

Tags: batch-file, cmd, command

I've got a simple command which copies all PDF files from a folder with subfolders to another path:

```
for /r "c:\users\user\documents" %i in (*.pdf) do copy "%~fi" "d:\alla\%~nxi"
```

How do I convert that command into a batch file? When I'm saving it from [Notepad](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notepad_%28software%29) as `script.bat` and run, nothing is happening.

Comment: This is one of those RTM moments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation (available by typing `for /?` or `help for` from a command prompt explains the problem. I've **emphasized** the relevant portion of the partial quote below.

> Runs a specified command for each file in a set of files.
>
> FOR %variable IN (set) DO command [command-parameters]

```
  %variable           Specifies a single letter replaceable parameter.
  (set)               Specifies a set of one or more files.  Wildcards may be used.
  command             Specifies the command to carry out for each file.
  command-parameters  Specifies parameters or switches for the specified command.
```

> **To use the FOR command in a batch program, specify %%variable instead
>   of %variable.**  Variable names are case sensitive, so %i is different
>   from %I.

So while your command works from the command line, in order to use it from a batch file you need to double the `%` signs preceding the variable.

```
for /r "c:\users\user\documents" %%i in (*.pdf) do copy "%%~fi" "d:\alla\%%~nxi"
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```bat
@for /r "c:\users\user\documents" %%i in (*.pdf) do @copy "%%~fi" "d:\alla\%%~nxi"
```